# Comparison between dates in SQL using to_timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, date

TWO Dates have to be compared , one in format MM/DD/YYYY  and another one in YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS.

how can this be done. i tried using to_timestamp but it is throwing an error like :

```
  AND TO_TIMESTAMP(PAYMENT_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')>=TO_TIMESTAMP( :L_RESEND_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
```

[Error] Execution (23: 27): ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: Have you considered using the [DATETIME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/datetime.html) data type to store your dates?

Comment: What are the data types of the various columns/ parameters?  Neither a `date` nor a `timestamp` has a format.  Only a `VARCHAR2` representing a date has a format.  But it's almost always an error to store date or timestamp data in a `VARCHAR2` column.

Comment: If `payment_date` is a `timestamp` or `date` column using `to_timestamp` is totally useless and may very well lead to this error.

Comment: @GarethD: you are linking to the **MySQL** manual, but user3809240 is using Oracle (which does not have a `datetime` data type).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My bad, I saw that the web page was `docs.oracle.com" and didn't bother reading what was on it properly. I did not realise the Oracle website had MySQL docs on it.... My point remains valid, although I probably should have said "Have you considered using [TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006050) to store you dates?"

Comment: PYMENT_DATE IS of type date l_resend_date varchar2 @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: If those are already `date` columns, then the expression `TO_TIMESTAMP(PAYMENT_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')` first converts `payment_date` to varchar using implicit data type conversion based on the current NLS settings, just to convert that `varchar` back to a timestamp. If you remove those two useless conversions, everything should be fine: `and payment_date >= :L_RESEND_DATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `payment_date` is already of type `date` you don't need to, and should not, be converting it. You are doing an implicit conversion from `date` to `varchar2` based on your NLS settings, and then an explicit conversion back with your specified format model, and as a_horse_with_no_name said, that's both pointless and prone to error. So you're effectively doing:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

If your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT is DD/MM/YYYY for example, that means you're doing:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(PAYMENT_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

... and trying to swap the month and day number over, which would explain your error. As soon as you have a day number that is greater than 12 that double conversion will error, and other values will be incorrect even if no error is thrown.

Don't convert your table column at all, just convert the parameter:

```
AND PAYMENT_DATE >= TO_DATE(:L_RESEND_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

I've used `to_date()` rather than `to_timestamp()` because that ends up matching the column's data type (and allows any index on that column to be used), and you don't need the fractional seconds precision that timestamps allow; I've also changed `HH` to `HH24` since you don't have an AM/PM indicator.

---

This is now comparing a `date` with a `date`. It isn't relevant here as you don't need the extra precision, but if you did ever want to convert a `date` to a `timestamp`, you wouldn't need to have an intermediate `varchar2` value, you could [cast the value](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions023.htm#SQLRF00613) instead with `CAST(PAYMENT_DATE AS TIMESTAMP)`.

Comment: Absolutely this... I didn't even consider the column could already be a date. And good catch with HH24!

Answer (score 1):

The following works perfectly:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
 WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP('11/23/2014 10:32:15','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')
       >=
       TO_TIMESTAMP( '2013/11/29 12:54:12','YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS');
```

So the solution is simple - most likely your Data is wrong... most likely some of your dates are DD/MM/YYYY or YYYY/DD/MM - If in doubt trust the error-message, which is very precise and clear - you have a Month-Value outside the range ;-)

Maybe try `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(PAYMENT_DATE,1,2)) > 12;` or otherwise do something similar with your bind-variable to find the dates which are wrong...

Oh and **ALWAYS STORE DATES AS DATES OR IN ISO-FORM**: [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: Since the OP did not mention one of his values is actually a date, refer to the answer of Alex Poole, just keeping this for people with a similar problem